# How does MVC pass datevalues to jQuery?

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to implement the [DateRange](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx) extension into a MVC site.

The site is trying to use this date format: yyyy/mm/dd (ie 2011/02/14).

When I try a 'Create New' on a page the jquery-ui.js throws an unhandled error on the parseDate function.  The parseDate functions shows 'm/d/yy' as the format and '2011/02/09' as the date value.

What is confusing me is how after changing all the m/d/yy formats to yy/mm/dd in the code that there is still the other format showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After constant tweaking the sample the only thing that appears to influence the date format is the 'Date.cshtml' file.  Changing this files format string will influence how the initial(default) date-time values show.  Changing the other C#/JS files seems to have no influence on how the datepicker displays the dateformat.

As a result of this I will be dropping this extension from my project...